# Autohotkey: Can't get the name and path of a pdf file

Tags: pdf, autohotkey, clipboard

The following code gets the selected text from a file after pressing ctrl+shift+c and appends its name and path to it, then copies it to the clipboard. It works with a .txt file, but not with a pdf file. How can I make it to work with **pdf** files?

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; **Hotkey to trigger the script**
^+c::

ClipWait, 1  ; Wait for the clipboard to contain text (timeout after 1 second).

; Retrieve the active window title (potential file name)
WinGetActiveTitle, active_title

; Check if the window title appears relevant to a file
if (RegExMatch(active_title, ".*\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|...)"))  ; Adjust file extensions as needed
{

  ; Extract the file name and path from the title
  if (RegExMatch(active_title, ".*\\(.*\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|...))", matches))
  {

    file_name := matches1
    file_path := matches2

    ; Combine file name, full path, and copied text
    clipboard := file_path . "\" . file_name . "`r`n" . clipboard

  }
  else
  {
    MsgBox, No file name or path found in window title.
  }
}
else
{
  ; Not a relevant file, so copy just the text
  Send, ^c
}

Return
```

[Active Window Info screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izqbh.png)

Comment: That script only works with programs that put the full path of the file in the window title. It works with Notepad++ but other programs are going to be very patchy and highly dependent on the program showing the path in that particular way. You are basically going to have to test every PDF reader you can find to see if they have the path in the window title bar or can be configured to show it. Adobe reader doesn't seem to have that ability https://www.google.com/search?q=adobe%20reader%20show%20full%20path%20of%20pdf

Comment: What program do you use to open PDF files?

Comment: @Relax it is the DrawboardPDF

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, it works with Notepad++

Comment: Is there another way to get that information, instead of reading the window title?

Comment: Right click the tray icon of the script and click `Window Spy`. What info shows  that tool when the window of your pdf program is active?

Comment: @Relax I get this message: "Could not launch WindowSpy.ahk or AU3_Spy.exe"

Comment: @Relax I am using the version 1.1.37.01. I get the same error message with Window Spy.  I understand that trying to read the title is not the way to go. Thank you.

Comment: Download https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.1/AutoHotkey112301_Install.exe > open that archiv with 7-Zip or another  file archiver > copy the file `AU3_Spy.exe` and > put it in the program files/AutoHotkey folder.

Comment: @Relax It shows only name of the file as the window title, not the path.

Comment: @Relax Link to the image is added.

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue? Giving feedback and sharing knowledge help other users who are searching for similar solutions. If you need more help, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Relax No, it did not work. I gave up. Thank you. Since I do not have enough credit, I am not allowed to rate your answer.

Comment: It should work if the option `Show recently used files` in the  [Folder Options](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/open-folder-options-explorer-windows/) is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program creates shortcuts of the opened files in the Recent Items folder you can try this:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force 
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

; Get the path of the recent items folder
RegRead, Recent, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, Recent

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===
            

#IfWinActive - Drawboard PDF ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow

    ; Press F1 to get the name and path of the pdf file opened in the active DrawboardPDF window:

    F1::
        WinGetActiveTitle, active_title
        active_title := StrSplit(active_title," ‎- Drawboard PDF").1
        If FileExist(Recent "\" active_title ".lnk")
        {
            FileGetShortcut, %Recent%\%active_title%.lnk, path
            MsgBox, Name = "%active_title%"`nPath = "%path%"
        }
        else
            MsgBox, path not found
    return

#IfWinActive    ; turn off context sensitivity
```

Comment: Make sure that the option `Show recently used files` in the  [Folder Options](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/open-folder-options-explorer-windows/) is enabled.